# Throw an Exception Object Creation

Tags: java, try-catch

Is an exception object created when a catch statement is implemented?

For example, catch (ArithmeticException someObject)

Does this object not have to explicitly be created as an instance?

Comment: It is not created in the catch clause. It is created by the method that caused it (inside your try-clause) with the `throw` keyword.

Comment: It is created by `throw` statement. You just catch it in `catch` block.

Comment: My question is that when an instance of ArithmeticException is created, why don't we have to use the key word "new". In java isn't it so that you have to use the keyword new for all cases?

Comment: @vladatr Actually, it is created by the `new` in `throw new ...`.  It is not the `throw` statement *per se*.

Comment: @Stephen C You are right. We should be very prrcise in giving explanations.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things **creating Instance of the Exception** the second **throwing the Exception**

**creating an Instance of The Exception** looks like creating any instance of Class for example `NullPointerException npe = new NullPointerException();` at this moment we didn't do any thing more than creating an instance, **some times we didn't create the instance of Exception by ourselves**  as we will see

**Throwing Exception**  after creating instance of Exception class we `throw` it, you can throw the Exception by yourself or the **JVM** will do

```
try
{
   int a = 10/0;
}catch(ArithmeticException  a)
{
     RuntimeException exception = new RuntimeException("a very bad error occured", a);
     throw exception;
}
```

when Java tried to compute `10/0` it encounter an arithmetic error so the **JVM** creates an instance of class `ArithmeticException` and throws this created instance which you catch it in your `catch` clause, where we create an instance of class `RuntimeException` it's just an object and then throw it using `throw`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an object. But you aren't creating an instance of it.

The `Exception` object instance is created when someone throws it.

```
try {
    Foo foo = null;
    foo.dofoo();
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
    // ...
}
```

In this particular case, the JVM created the `NullPointerException` object instance that you are handling in the catch block.

In few words imagine that in some part of the JVM there's something like:

```
if (obj == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

<sub>**Do not** take the previous code sample serious. It's an exemplification of Exception throwing.</sub>